# Custom play button for slider input in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html says that you can modify the appearance of the play button in slider input by using HTML tags or a character vector. I want my play button to be a bit bigger or use an image instead, I can't quite get it to work and can't find an example of someone who has used the playButton or pauseButton parameter on Google. Any tips?

Adding the following as a parameter:

```
playbutton=HTML("<img src=\"~/www/play.png\">")
```

gives an unused argument error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

playButton is not an argument to sliderInput.  Instead, playButton is an argument to animationOptions which is used for animate argument of sliderInput.

See here for details:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html

However, I tried setting up a custom play button in this manner and it did not work.  You may need to just write the HTML of the slider yourself, which is not at all hard to do.  Here is the HTML output of a generic slider w/ animation controls:

```
      <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
        <label class="control-label" for="bins">Number of bins:</label>
        <input class="js-range-slider" id="bins" data-min="1" data-max="50" data-from="30" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="9.8" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-keyboard="true" data-keyboard-step="2.04081632653061"/>
        <div class="slider-animate-container">
          <a href="#" class="slider-animate-button" data-target-id="bins" data-interval="1000" data-loop="FALSE">
            <span class="play">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="pause">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

You can edit the HTML for the play/pause sections to look how you like as well as the various parameters of the slider.

Comment: Word. Thanks, I wasn't reading the documentation very mindfully

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to integrate the raw HTML into the shiny r code?

Comment: take the HTML code, add your img code between the span tags, paste it in to R, switch all the quotes with singles (" -> '), then quote the whole thing and set is as character.  Then, use the HTML function to add it into your UI.r.  That should get your close enough and the rest should be fixable with some tinkering.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but wanted to add another approach as there isn't much information out there!

If you simply want to make the play/pause button bigger, you can do this with css. The important thing to note is that it is done by changing the font size of the icon, not any other size parameters like height or width. Add a line like this into your UI (mine is at the start of `DashboardBody()`, though it will depend on the structure of your app what you have):

```
tags$head(tags$style(type='text/css', ".slider-animate-button { font-size: 20pt !important; }"))
```